# Annoying Stumbleupon chrome addon

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, stumbleupon

I like using stumbleupon addon. But stumbleupon insists on imposing itself on every tab I open. Is there a way to limit stumbleupon toolbar to only 1 tab? I am using Google Chrome on Windows 7.

Update: I don't just need to review sites, I would also like to stumble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstall the add on and do it this way

http://blogote.com/2008/featured-article/stumebleupon-without-firefox-addons-on-google-chromesafariopera-browser.html

"Using chrome addon type bookmarklet – Drag this Stumble it on your Chrome bookmark and whenever you want to review a website just click on Stumble it so that you can review the site without any stumbleupon toolbar."

Comment: I'm not just looking for something to adding reviews. I also need to stumble. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Would not be right for me to add a solution you discovered to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the solution myself. Uninstalling the add on and stumbling from the stumbleupon website itself solves the problem. The complete stubmleupon toolbar is visible and restricted to only one tab. This, along with Moab's solution provides the complete functionality of the add on.